# Android - how to create fixed tabs

Tags: android, tabs

I'm trying to create fixed tabs in android, but all code examples I tried has deprecated functions.

Does anybody have an updated link that explains how to make fixed tabs?

**EDIT**:

I tried using tabhost and actionbar...

Thanks

Comment: you can try this once http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html

Comment: yes, thanks... I tried it as well. I finally used an example I found with SlidingTabLayout with extends HorizontalScrollView. Hope I can make it work....

Comment: @MaayanCastel: but why not use the approach I suggested ? Were you not able to implement it ? Its quite easy. You don't need to use any other third-party libraries for this :)

Answer (score 0):

You refer at this tabs?
http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html

If the Tabs aren't fixed to the top by default you can do this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal" >
   <!-- Put your tabs here-->
 <ScrollView >

    <LinearLayout>

      <!-- Put your Views here-->

    </LinearLayout>

 </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

You can check some examples for tabs here

[exampleTabs1](http://androidexample.com/Tab_Layout_%7C_TabBar_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=103&aaid=125)
[exampleTabs2](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/)

Example from developer.android

[Creating Swipe Views with Tabs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)

Comment: Fixed, not scrollable, can look like facebook for example

Comment: If they aren't fixed by default try to use two different layout
To the first LinearLayout put the tab.
To the second LinearLayout use the ScrollView.
Now i update my answere so you can see what i say

Comment: Thanks! but these examples use TabActivity which is deprecated and ActionBar which has also quite a lot of deprecated funtions

Comment: Have you tried as I said with the LinearLayout? The first window of code.
I'm not sure if it's work, but you can try if don't find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I finally used this link:
http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html?showComment=1427797870232#c2515097882322319034

Maayan